# assert_called with any argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, assertion

In my unit test case, I'm trying to check if a particular function is being called or not using this:

```
mock_wait_until_complete.assert_called()
```

The function wait until complete takes 2 arguments: (uid: string, time: int)

I want to build it in such a way that it passes the test case irrespective of any arguments that are passed.

Is there any way to achieve this?

** Edit

```
AssertionError: 
Expected call: wait_until_complete('bt_url, verify=False)
Actual call: wait_until_complete(<MagicMock name='post().text' id='2039952'>)
```

So, right now I'm getting this error with this piece of code during testing, but its working exactly how I want it to. So, to basically ignore this error, I want it to accept/assert True no matter what argument is being passed..

Comment: I don't understand "I want to build it in such a way that it passes the test case irrespective of any arguments that are passed."

Comment: I've edited the question, hope this helps! Thank you

Comment: `assert_called()` already does what you want. Your error message seems to be coming from completely different code from what you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comments, I solved this particular code by using:

```
assertEqual(mocked_wait_until_complete.call_count, 1)
```

This basically checks if the function is called once irrespective of any arguments passed.